# Is this an expression: "Talk to you during the week"

Tags: idioms

Like a good son, I call my mother every week on Sunday. When we're finishing our conversation, she closes with *Talk to you during the week*. She uses this phrase like most people would use *Talk to you later* or just *goodbye*. She obviously doesn't mean it literally, because we rarely call during the week unless something comes up (like she's having a computer problem she needs my help with).

I've never heard anyone else use this phrase, and couldn't find it with a google search -- is it just an ideosyncracy of hers?  She grew up in 1940's Brooklyn, is it something that might have come from the Jewish community there?

Comment: I haven't heard it; my dad grew up in 1940s Bronx (also Jewish), and I grew up in Manhattan.

Comment: Sounds like a typical expression a mother may say, suggesting "hope to hear from you sooner than next Sunday" :).

Comment: @Josh61 You just try to get my mother on the phone. It's Sunday dinner or nothin ;)

Comment: 'Talk to you + temporal expression' doesn't have to be all that common for it to be acceptable conversationally. 'Talk to you sometime after half term.' Here, the 'sometime' has been conversationally deleted; 'during' usually refers to an extended period rather than a precise moment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I obviously understand it, so it's acceptable, it just seems weird. Using a specific time seems strange when you know full well that it's not going to happen during that time. It's like saying "See you Wednesday" instead of "See you later" when parting, when you have no specific plans to get together on Wednesday.

Comment: We can only discuss commonly (or, with more courage, semi-locally) accepted meanings. 'Talk to you during the week.' is conversationally acceptable with regard to grammar; if you're asking about whether it's standard to use it to mean 'talk to you later, but perhaps not for a month or two', the answer is (almost certainly) 'no'. However, people _do_ commonly make exaggerated offers that they really know they will only go part way to fulfilling. This is just one of those, and your mother has settled on it as a set expression **for herself**.

Comment: So you're saying it probably **is** an individual ideosyncracy, not something she likely learned from others. That was my question.

Comment: @ Barmar This is definitely an idiosyncrasy as the sentence and scenario suggest that it should be taken literally. Although I do know of a few people however, who say: "Talk to you soon", and end up not talking to me for weeks or even months.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard way to say goodbye: "See you later".

But of course on the telephone, there is no seeing.  So someone may have thought to replace it with "Talk to you later".  It is not a standard phrase, but everyone will understand.

What about "during the week"?  I don't know.  Maybe she is giving you a hint that she would welcome more frequent calls.

Comment: You might be right about the "hint". She doesn't seem to say it much any more, maybe she's finally given up, perhaps subconsciously.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit non-standard, but I wouldn't say there's anything wrong with it - I'd say it has the same meaning as 'Talk to you later this week.'